# Unable to Log Python List Objects as Message in Graylog

Tags: graylog2, graylog, gelf, graylog3

I am trying to send Python List as Log Message to Graylog. The approach that i am using is "Sending GELF messages via HTTP using curl" mentioned in http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/gelf.html

But when i send data as below:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"log_type":"debug", "short_message": "[1,4,5,2]",  "block_id":"TEST_LOGGING"}'  'http://<host>:12201/gelf'
```

it works perfectly fine.

Where as on sending message as below Logs nothing.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"log_type":"debug", "short_message": [1,4,5,2],  "block_id":"TEST_LOGGING"}'  'http://<host>:12201/gelf'
```

I am unable to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using '[graypy](https://github.com/severb/graypy)'. It lets you post logs to graylog using TCP port 12201 for the input streams creating. It also lets you add additional parameters, that you can tag to a message using adapters. The documentation has examples for adapters.